# how A: Into<String> implies in rust

Tags: rust

I am recently into the rust learning, here is a simple code

```
pub struct User {
  #[validate(length(min = 1))]
  pub name: String,
  #[validate(email)]
  pub email: String,
  pub password: String,
  pub updated_at: Date,
  pub created_at: Date,
  pub locked_at: Option<Date>,
}

impl User {
  pub fn new<A, B, C>(name: A, email: B, password_hash: C) -> Self
  where
    A: Into<String>,
    B: Into<String>,
    C: Into<String>,
  {
    let now = date::now();
    Self {
      name: name.into(),
      email: email.into(),
      password: password_hash.into(),
      updated_at: now,
      created_at: now,
      locked_at: None,
    }
  }

}
```

however I am not quite understanding why it designs to make A: Into, what is the its use in this scenario

Comment: From your question it is not clear what you're asking. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: It lets you pass in `String`s, but also `&str` or anything that can be converted into `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notation is mainly for *convenience*.
Fundamentally, `User::new()` needs owned strings because its purpose is to store them, but in case we only have (at the call site) a `&str`, this would imply to build the owned string at the call site (more code to write for the caller).
Thanks to the `Into<String>` constraint on the generic type, if we already provide a `String`, nothing more is done with `.into()`, but if we only provide a `&str` (a string literal for example), the called function itself will create the expected `String` thanks to `.into()`.

Please find below some examples in order to illustrate this idea.
There is also an illustration of the reciprocal idea, in which the function should fundamentally work with a `&str` but accepts anything that could be considered as this type.
The effect of this *convenience* is visible on the errors which are generated or not.

Of course, the same logic applies to other types not related to strings; owned vectors and slices for example.

```rust
// the two parameters must have type String
fn requires_owned_strings(
    param1: String,
    param2: String,
) -> (String, String) {
    let owned_string_1: String = param1;
    let owned_string_2: String = param2;
    (owned_string_1, owned_string_2)
}

// the two parameters must be convertible into String
fn would_like_owned_strings<S1, S2>(
    param1: S1,
    param2: S2,
) -> (String, String)
where
    S1: Into<String>,
    S2: Into<String>,
{
    let owned_string_1: String = param1.into();
    let owned_string_2: String = param2.into();
    (owned_string_1, owned_string_2)
}

// the two parameters must have type &str
fn requires_string_slices(
    param1: &str,
    param2: &str,
) -> (usize, usize) {
    let string_slice_1: &str = param1;
    let string_slice_2: &str = param2;
    (string_slice_1.len(), string_slice_2.len())
}

// the two parameters must be visible as &str
fn would_like_string_slices<S1, S2>(
    param1: S1,
    param2: S2,
) -> (usize, usize)
where
    S1: AsRef<str>,
    S2: AsRef<str>,
{
    let string_slice_1: &str = param1.as_ref();
    let string_slice_2: &str = param2.as_ref();
    (string_slice_1.len(), string_slice_2.len())
}

fn main() {
    {
        println!("~~~~ requires_owned_strings() ~~~~");
        let a = String::from("AAA");
        let b = String::from("BBB");
        println!("{:?}", requires_owned_strings(a, b));
        let c = String::from("CCC");
        // ERROR: expected `String`, found `&str`
        // println!("{:?}", requires_owned_strings(c, "DDD"));
        println!("{:?}", requires_owned_strings(c, "DDD".to_string()));
    }
    {
        println!("~~~~ would_like_owned_strings() ~~~~");
        let a = String::from("AAA");
        let b = String::from("BBB");
        println!("{:?}", would_like_owned_strings(a, b));
        let c = String::from("CCC");
        println!("{:?}", would_like_owned_strings(c, "DDD"));
    }
    {
        println!("~~~~ requires_string_slices() ~~~~");
        let a: &str = "AAA";
        let b: &str = "BBB";
        println!("{:?}", requires_string_slices(a, b));
        let c = String::from("CCC");
        // ERROR: expected `&str`, found `String`
        // println!("{:?}", requires_string_slices(c, "DDD"));
        println!("{:?}", requires_string_slices(c.as_str(), "DDD"));
    }
    {
        println!("~~~~ would_like_string_slices() ~~~~");
        let a: &str = "AAA";
        let b: &str = "BBB";
        println!("{:?}", would_like_string_slices(a, b));
        let c = String::from("CCC");
        println!("{:?}", would_like_string_slices(c, "DDD"));
    }
}
/*
~~~~ requires_owned_strings() ~~~~
("AAA", "BBB")
("CCC", "DDD")
~~~~ would_like_owned_strings() ~~~~
("AAA", "BBB")
("CCC", "DDD")
~~~~ requires_string_slices() ~~~~
(3, 3)
(3, 3)
~~~~ would_like_string_slices() ~~~~
(3, 3)
(3, 3)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

The intent of this code is to let the user pass three possibly different things that all can be converted to string.

1. `T: Into<String>` means "some type that can be turned into a string"
2. `A`, `B`, `C` are separate generics, because otherwise passing, i.e. a `&str` for `name` would force two other parameters to be `&str` as well.

Comment: To be more precise, `T: Into<String>` means that you can pass anything that implements the `Into<String>` trait. So you could also pass whatever `X` other type that `impl Into<String> for X`.